# How do I find the index of the max value in a specific range of np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have intensity values over time that I saved in a one-dimensional numpy array called `cell`. I calculate a maximum during a certain time window by:

```py
peak = max(cell[750:791])
```

Now I want to have the index of this specific peak value but only in the same time window. I tried:

```py
idx_peak = np.where(cell[750:791] == peak)
```

But this seems to give me all the indices from the entire array. How can I apply `np.where` in my specific time window? I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
idx_peak = cell[750:791].argmax()
```

Comment: That didn't seem to solve the problem... The resulting index is at the very beginning of my trace.

Comment: does adding `750` to the result helps? as `argmax` gives you the max index within the range of `750 to 791` so if you want the absolute index you should add `750` to it

Comment: YES!!!! thank you so much ! Addition of 750 to argmax did the trick.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: @na_mu please accept the answer if your query has been addressed, this will mark the question as answered